# SVN to GIT Migration - How to maintain maven module hierarchy?

Tags: git, svn

We are in the process of SVN to GIT Migration. In SVN we used to have following maven structure:

**core-common** [pom maven parent module]

- **common-exceptions** [jar maven module]
- **common-data-access** [jar maven module]
- **common-utils** [jar maven module]

**App-Module**  [pom maven parent module]

- **Services** [jar maven module]
- **rest-resources**  [war maven module]

If any new developer wants to setup workspace in eclipse, he has to do following:

1. Checkout **core-common** resulting all children (common-exceptions, common-utils, common-) checkout and then build
2. Checkout **App-Module** resulting all children (Services, rest-resources) checkout and then build
3. deploy **rest-resources** web into server, test and start development

Now if we move to GIT, what kind of hierarchy we should follow. Should we follow flat structure without having parent-child module concept but just all projects at same level? If yes, doesn't developer have to clone 5 modules from GIT separately where in SVN he has to checkout only parent but not even worry about children.

**Flat Hierarchy**

- **common-exceptions** [jar maven module]
- **common-data-access** [jar maven module]
- **common-utils** [jar maven module]
- **Services** [jar maven module]
- **rest-resources**  [war maven module]

Or, its better to follow same approach that we used to have in SVN. Any specific standard should be followed in GIT?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are happy with the current setup. You can still use it in the same way with `git`.

Comment: Actually Its not about what I like. Its about any standard we should follow while moving to GIT. But I think https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot is having same hierarchy so I can still follow same.